# Include shortcode within contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, contact-form-7

Using contact form 7, when a customer fills in a form it sends me an email with the data the customer has entered. Within this email I want to include a shortcode I have in use on the website.

The shortcode I am using just displays some text, and works as it should on the website.

However if I add it to the contact form email, it does not display the content of the shortcode, it just displays the shortcode as text... [buf_reg]

Is it possible to display shortcodes in the contact form 7 email? Or any other email for that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet of code in your functions.php to make shortcodes work in the e-mails sent by Contact Forms 7:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_special_mail_tags', 'your_special_mail_tag', 10, 3 );

function your_special_mail_tag( $output, $name, $html ) {
    if ( 'buf_reg' == $name )
        $output = do_shortcode( '[buf_reg]' );

    return $output;
}
```

Source: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-shortcode-in-emails/#post-3931725

Comment: I can display shortcodes within the form which is what this plugin does, however i need the, to display within the email that is sent. Thanks